# facebook Comments Box plugin

Tags: facebook, comments

I want use the comments box on my site to comment posts. I paste the code generated in my page

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=IDAPP";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://facebook.3rdplace.com/zend/ibs_post.php?id=<?=$id_post?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

If I post a comment, it appears, but it's not saved on Graph.
Where's the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `data-href` URL is accessable externally. Apart from that you could try and debug it using the `comment.create` event.

Like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(comment) {
    console.log(comment);    // looking for comment.commentID - https://graph.facebook.com/<comment_id>
});
```